# Castle Monorail and Ninject 2 integration

Tags: ninject, castle-monorail

I want to use Ninject 2 on Castle Monorail. Searching on google, I found nothing about this.

I know there is Windsor which magically can integrate with Monorail, same as Ninject (with MVC extension) with ASP.NET MVC.

What steps I need to do to integrate DI framework (other than Windsor) with Monorail ? (any website link, tutorial, or code sample (preferably using Ninject 2))

fyi, I'm using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any documentation about this, but it's quite simple really. There's no magic to it. Since MonoRail and Windsor are completely separate projects, all you have to do is [see how they integrate](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.MonoRail/tree/master/src/Castle.MonoRail.WindsorExtension), then do the same for Ninject instead of Windsor.

More concretely, start with the [MonoRailFacility](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.MonoRail/blob/master/src/Castle.MonoRail.WindsorExtension/MonoRailFacility.cs) which is the root of the integration. Instead of a Windsor facility, you'd use a Ninject module. Note it registers some components: IControllerTree, IWizardPageFactory, etc. The most important is IControllerFactory, which lets you resolve controllers from the container (in your case Ninject). You can leave all others as default for now (e.g. IFilterFactory/DefaultFilterFactory), and implement them as needed (i.e. when you need container control of filters).

Then call `ServiceProviderLocator.Instance.AddLocatorStrategy(new NinjectAccessorStrategy());` where `NinjectAccessorStrategy` is an implementation of `IAccessorStrategy` which returns the Ninject kernel as a `Castle.Core.IServiceProviderEx` (which is nothing but a trivial extension of `System.IServiceProvider`). Since the Ninject kernel already implements `IServiceProvider`, it's trivial to write an adapter for `IServiceProviderEx`.

Comment: While doing this, I found the NinjectServiceProvider needs to use `kernel.TryGet<T>()` instead of `kernel.Get<T>()` so that it will return null if a type is not registered. This triggers MonoRail to use the default implementation.